# How to include div value in email form and then sends to an email adress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i would like to ask if is it possible to include div value to an email form and then send it to a specific email address

For example
i have div field with id=field1 and text inside as field1 (which would be interchangeable by a js.

and we sum everything in an form with name, email, the div field 1 and submit button

Is it possible to include the div field to email as html text, and then send it to email?
In js or jquery ?

i saw the topic ***email a div from a form***, but that isnt working it gives me email with null text, not the div text.

Thanks in front for helping.

Comment: you should ask 2 questions, one regarding the client side script/html, the other "how to send emails from php"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Div's content aren't sent with the form. You should use a textarea element.

Comment: i did achieve my goal with texarea elements, i used same id for name= there and it works perfectly thx friends for fast responses :)

Answer (score 3):

With JQuery, you can do:

```
$('#textfield').val($('#field1').html());
```

Assuming that your text field has id `textfield`.

The `val()` function gets or sets the content. 
The `html()` function gets the inner html of an element.

More info at http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page
http://api.jquery.com/val/
http://api.jquery.com/html/

And the you can submit your form, by:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

Assuming the id of your form is `myForm`.

Then, to send the email, use your server side technology.

Comment: Or you can put a hidden field and populate the field using the html() function as bluefoot mentioned in the form submit() event before the form submits.

Comment: The content of the div won't be sent with the form.

Answer (score 1):

if the div text is available beforehand, you can probably place it in a hidden field instead, e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" value="field1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use either a hidden input field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="div_text" value="..." />
```

Or Ajax:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
   $.post('ajax.php', {'div_text' : $('#div').text()}, function() {
      ...
      return false;
   });
});
```

Comment: the problem with hidden input field, it that my div is interchangeable by id and i tried with input field but it doesn't change it. i will try with ajax to see if it works.

Comment: Give it a try and post your code here if it doesn't work. If Ajax would feel superfluous, though, you'd rather go with bluefoot's solution.